# Infopath storing data in Sharepoint Form Library and sending data to Quickbooks

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, quickbooks

So we have a client that is wanting to replace all of their forms they use with digital versions where the data entered into them are stored in a centralized database for reporting. One of the main features required is when financial data is entered into a form, the relevant information should be update in QuickBooks. Specifically, instead of filling out a donation slip, putting it into a file for a donator, bringing up Quickbooks and recording the donation they want to have an application where they enter the donation/donator info which is stored in a database and, using the Quickbooks SDK, updates the daily deposit/donations/etc info in QuickBooks automatically.

My boss is trying to convince me to make a custom application to handle the whole thing, but I've been considering trying to pitch an Infopath + Sharepoint solution to him for the form management. However, I have absolutely no experience with either, so I don't know if any kind of integration with Quickbooks would be possible. So would an integration infopath/sharepoint with Quickbooks be feasible, and can you give me tips on where to look for info on how to implement it. Also, hiring a 'SharePoint Developer' is out of the question. So would a VB.Net/C# developer who has experience with web application development be able to address the programming skills required for a solution?

I'm open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a .NET developer could probably handle this situation.  You could possibly write code in the Infopath forms themselves, or create SharePoint workflows (using Visual Studio).  It would probably be a decently complex and hard to maintain solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I have not expirience with Quickbooks... If Quickbooks has web services to perform operations you are interested in you most likely will be able to make InfoPath form to collect/submit data.

InfoPath alone (as client application part of Office) may be enough - you should be able to quiclky prototype form you have InfoPath installed. For server side rendering of the InfoPath forms you need Enterprise edition of the SharePoint Server - not sure if this task alone would justify the purchase.